# JS lodash [1, 2] => {1: 'test', 2: 'test'}

Tags: javascript, lodash

There is an array:

```
var array = [{test: 1}, {test: 2}, {test: 3}]
```

I need to get:

```
{1: 'random_value', 2: 'random_value', 3: 'random_value'}
```

I'm doing:

```
var values_test = _.map(array, 'test');
```

What to do next?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce()` to get desired result.

```js
var array = [{test: 1}, {test: 2}, {test: 3}];

var result = array.reduce(function(r, o) {
  r[o.test] = 'random_value';
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

With Lodash

```js
var array = [{test: 1}, {test: 2}, {test: 3}];

var result = _.reduce(array, function(r, o) {
  r[o.test] = 'random_value';
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
var array = [{
  test: 1
}, {
  test: 2
}, {
  test: 3
}]
var r = _.map(array, x => {
  let o = {}
  o[x.test] = 'random value'
  return o
});
console.log(r)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```